# Post type to appear on every page on site

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development

What's the best way to create a post type that will appear on every page? This will contain the address information to go in the footer, and be limited to one entry. Does it need to be a custom post type?

Comment: No it doesn't need to be a post type. It could just a widget. As long as your theme has a widget area in the footer there's nothing stopping you adding a Text or HTML block/widget with your address, without any other coding required.

Comment: If the idea is to just have a place to enter contact information that will appear in the footer, I think a custom post type is overkill. If your site is using Advanced Custom Fields, take a look at the Options Page feature, otherwise, I'd suggest looking into how to add meta fields to the Theme Customizer (Appearance > Customize) instead. That way you'd just have a set of input fields somewhere that you'd fill in this data instead of having its own post type.

Comment: The ACF method looks good, so will probably go with that!

Comment: No need to manage with custom post type, because it's simple one entry and it's common for all pages, so try to manage with ACF if already installed or try with Text Widget!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.